# Matlab-Output values of column 3, when element of column 1 is A, element of column 2 is B using loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

Good morning/afternoon ~

I have a matrix `H` with size of 6800x3. 
I need to find all value of column 3, for [col 1 = `A` and col 2 = `B`] throughout the whole matrix. For all the combination of col 1 and col 2.

How could I find the value through loop?

```
[M N]= size(H);  %M = 6800, N = 3
x = H(:,1);     % column 1
y = H(:,2);     % column 2
z = H(:,3);     % column 3
for i= 1:M 
    if H(M:1)==A && H(M:2)==B  %for every combination of x and y
    Output=Z(M,3);                %Output all value of Z 
end
```

Any help will be appreciated. =D

Thank you ~

For example,

```
H = [1 2 1 ;...
     1 2 3 ;...
     2 2 5 ;...
     1 2 8 ]
```

for A=1, B=2,

```
z = [1 3 8]
```

Something like this..

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Output = z(M,3)` ? or something along this line?

Comment: So for the combination of `x(3)` and `y(6)`, what `z` do you want in `Output`?

Comment: Can you provide an example for input and output?

Comment: @Shai yup, Output =z(M,3)

Comment: Your example makes no sense: according to question you check the first two columns and output the third, while in the example you checked first and third column and output the second.

Comment: opps, edited the example. Now it should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without loop

```
Output = H( H(:,1) == A & H(:,2) == B, 3 );
```

For example:

```
>>  H = [1 2 1 ;...
         1 2 3 ;...
         2 2 3 ;...
         1 2 8 ]
>> A = 1; B = 2;
>> Output = H( H(:,1) == A & H(:,2) == B ,3 )
Output =
     1
     3
     8
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!I need to find all the combinations of x (column 1) and y (column 2). where A and B are values of x and y.

Comment: Yup it works for the example!Thanks! However for the original matrix with size of (6800x3), in order to find all the combination of X and Y (A and B), I think loop is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to group by columns 1 and 2.
Here is one way to do that:

```
H = [1 2 1 ;...
     1 2 3 ;...
     2 2 5 ;...
     1 2 8 ;...
     2 2 9];

[~, I, J] = unique(H(:, 1:2), 'rows');
result = accumarray(J, (1:length(J))', [], @(x) {H(x, :)});
```

And the result will be:

```
>> result{:}

ans =

     1     2     3
     1     2     8
     1     2     1


ans =

     2     2     9
     2     2     5
```

Comment: If this is indeed what you were looking for, you should consider accepting the answer ;)